# Where are SSH processes actually processed? (locally or on on the server)

Tags: ssh, runtime

Ok, kinda weird question but where are processes called from ssh by a remote user actually run? I had thought it was on the server itself but I was testing some code on my home network and found that running a particular script directly on the server (raspberry pi 3) takes about twice as long (60.36 s) as when I run the same process when I ssh into the server (31.7 s) from a MacBook pro.

The script simply runs a large for loop that performs a basic arithmetic operation and prints the result to the console. Additionally the script runs about 10X faster if the print statement is left out and the runtime for both local and remote become about the same.

Any ideas what is going on here? If anything I figured it might be the other way around and maybe packets were bottle necking each iteration, but now it seems more dependent on where the script is initiated and the respective processing power.

Comment: When you type ssh <remote_host> *command*, *command* runs on the remote_host. When you type ssh <remote_host>, then get a shell prompt on the remote host, then type *command*, *command* runs on the remote_host. Does that answer your question?

Comment: So either way your saying the processor and other resources of the remote host perform operations. But why is there such a large and consistent difference in runtime in the experiment I described?

Comment: So I explored what you were describing and got some more odd results.

Comment: When I SSH into the server, cd into the working directory and run the script it takes 32.7 s. However when I try what you described above "ssh user@myServer python Desktop/Python/TestSSH.ph" it finishes in 18.3 s. However if I open a terminal on the server directly (not through ssh) it takes about 60 s. What is causing these time differences?

Comment: `ssh` (despite the name) is *just* a connection tool. It connects your local standard input/output/error to a process that runs on another machine. However, what is the exact command you are using?

Comment: @chepner, in the first example I use "ssh user@myServer" to first open a prompt, then I use "cd Desktop/Python" to get to the directory, then I ran "python TestSSH.py". Which finishes in 32.7 s. Next I used the command "ssh user@myServer python Desktop/Python/TestSSH.ph" which completes in 18.3 s. But when I run the same script on the server itself (no ssh) "cd Desktop/Python" then "python TestSSH.py" it actually takes just over 60 s to run.

Comment: This is basically the opposite of what I had expected. I figured that since SSH uses a TCP connection that if I use print statements in the code the packet transmission and encryption of each print statement might bottle neck the process and cause it to run slower. Instead the result was the opposite and running directly on the server takes longer. The server is just a raspberry Pi 3 and I use a Mac to remote login. So based on the relative processing power it almost seems like the processing is being done on whatever device opened the SSH connection.